# how to access img in deny all folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a folder 'screens' full of images, in this folder i have a .htaccess :

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
Allow from 1xx.xx.xx.xxx
```

(it's the ip of the server)

So whithin my server, i have access to the information of that folder, and i can include the img's BUT i cant show the img, so

```
<img src="screens/img.png"/>
```

Recieve a "forbidden access" error.

I only show the screens in on file "test.php" and you have to be in a session to access test.php.

so i tried

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
Allow from 1xx.xx.xx.xxx
<Files test.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

But it still doesnt work. Any sugestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a php proxy using

```
file_get_contents("IMG PATH HERE");
```

then return it with the correct header.
PNG/JPG or whatever it is..

The HTML code would point to the php file for example with an id or path:

```
<img src="image.php?id=IMGID" />
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I even put a condition on the session on the image.php file !